# Hive query regexp_extract failing

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to use regexp_extract to extract my required data from a column(string datatype) in my table, Im using this query:

`select regexp_extract(concat(column_name,;),'.*a2=?(.*?);',1) from table;`

But I get an error:

`FAILED: ParseException line 1:43 cannot recognize input near '.' '*' 'a2' in select expression`

I'm at my wit's end with this, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Can regexp_replace not be used on columns?
Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using hive version 0.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out,
in hive you need to escape the semi-colon.

Hope this helps someone.

EDIT: Here's the answer that worked:

`regexp_extract(concat(column_name,'\;'),'.*a2=?(.*?)\;',1)`

I am concatenating a ';' because my logic requires it.

Answer (score 0):

This should replace semicolons with '\073' in the script below.

Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.4.3.3-2)

```
select regexp_extract(concat("columna2=blablablatest",'\073'),'.*a2=?(.*?)\073',1);
```